# legend in bokeh UMAP shows only one entry

Tags: python, legend, bokeh, legend-properties, runumap

Hi there I just managed to get this plot done in `bokeh`, so I imagine there are many things that could be improved. Nonetheless, what bothers me the most is that I cannot figure out how to have all entries for my eight populations in the UMAP plot...
Right now it shows only one entry which I don't know if it's associated to the correct population, and I manipulate with `legend_lable`.

What I actually want to show is a legend with all eight populations (EUR, SIB, AFR, SAS, CEA, OCE, MENA and AME) and their associated colors. *See* below for the code I used and and example for the plot. Any help is appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import bokeh.plotting as bp

from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, show
from umap import UMAP


umap = pd.read_csv("SGDP_download/SGDP_bi_snps_norm-2.eigenvec", sep="\t")
umap.rename(columns={"#IID": "#ID"}, inplace=True)

loc = pd.read_csv("SGDP_download/pca_loc_fix_python-order.txt")
colors = pd.read_csv("SGDP_download/bokeh_colors.txt")

eigenval = pd.read_csv("SGDP_download/SGDP_bi_snps_norm-2.eigenval", header=None)
pve = round(eigenval / (eigenval.sum(axis=0))*100, 2)
pve.head()


umap.sort_values('#ID', inplace=True)
umap.insert(loc=1, column='#LOC', value=loc)
umap.rename(columns={'#ID': 'ID', '#LOC': 'LOC'}, inplace=True)


regions_umap = umap.iloc[:, 2:12]

umap_plot = UMAP(n_components=2, init="random", random_state=15)
umap_proj = umap_plot.fit_transform(regions_umap)
#umap_proj.view()
#umap_proj.shape

df = pd.DataFrame(umap_proj, columns=['UMAP1', 'UMAP2'])
df.insert(loc=0, column='population', value=loc)
df.insert(loc=1, column='color', value=colors)
df.index = umap["ID"]

source=ColumnDataSource(df)
#source
df


TOOLS="hover,crosshair,pan,wheel_zoom,zoom_in,zoom_out,box_zoom,undo,redo,reset,tap,save,box_select,poly_select,lasso_select,examine,help"

fig = figure(tools=TOOLS, x_axis_label='UMAP1', y_axis_label='UMAP2')
fig.scatter(x=df['UMAP1'], y=df['UMAP2'], color=df['color'], size=5, legend_label='population',
            fill_alpha=0.6, line_color=None)

fig.legend.location = "top_left"
fig.legend.title = "metapopulations"

show(fig)
```

[image]

P.S. as a side note it is possible to have the legend at the bottom of the plot with the legend title centered?

**EDIT** this is what the df looks like @droumis

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a legend entry for each unique key in your column "population" the best is to use `groupby()` from pandas and loop over the groups and plot the scatter for each.

See the minimal example below.

```py
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import Legend
output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'UMAP1': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'UMAP2': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'population':['EUR', 'SIB', 'AME']*2,
    'color':['#1e90ff', '#bdb76b', '#eeaeee']*2,
})

p = figure()
legend = Legend(orientation='horizontal')
p.add_layout(legend, 'below')

grouper = df.groupby('population')
for label, g in grouper:
    p.scatter(g['UMAP1'], g['UMAP2'], color=g['color'], legend_label=label)
show(p)
```

[image: simple plot with 3 colors and legend entries]

Comment: I see how it works! Thanks a lot, I was reading a bunch of similar example but couldn't extrapolate correctly because of my limited experience so far; really appreciated the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `legend_field` parameter instead of `legend_label`, like this:

`fig.scatter(x=df['UMAP1'], y=df['UMAP2'], color=df['color'], size=5, legend_field='population', fill_alpha=0.6, line_color=None)`

I think you can use something like `fig.legend.location = "bottom_center"` to move the legend down and center it.

Comment: thanks a lot. The positioning of the legend is now at the bottom of the plot, centered in the middle. However, the `legend_field` attributes when used returns this error: "ERROR:bokeh.core.validation.check:E-1001 (BAD_COLUMN_NAME): Glyph refers to nonexistent column name. This could either be due to a misspelling or typo, or due to an expected column being missing."